# Is there a more idiomatic way in Rust to handle similar methods?

Tags: rust

My program loads two file types, `sql` or `csv`, makes manipulations, and then saves them out. I have two structs, one for the preliminary serialization and another for the output.

Both files follow the same process and thus, have the same methods (but the logic obviously differs).

I tried using a trait to group these methods, but I couldn't get it to work because I needed to tell the compiler what the *type* was ahead of time.

What I have:

```
struct DerivedTable { /* ... */ }

struct NewTable { /* ... */ }

struct CsvFile { /* ... */ }

struct NewCsv { /* ... */ }

// ... load some files from a dir
for node in dir_of_files {
            match get_extension(path) {
                "csv" => {
                    let model = CsvFile::new_from_file(node.path.to_path_buf())?;
                    let new_csv = NewCsv::from(model);
                    new_csv.export(&out_path)?;
                    Ok(node.name.clone())
                }
                "sql" => {
                    let model = DerivedTable::new_from_file(node.path.to_path_buf())?;
                    let new_table = NewTable::from(model);
                    new_table.export(&out_path)?;
                    Ok(node.name.clone())
                }
                _ => panic!("Illegal file type passed"),
            }
        })
}
```

I'm wondering if it's possible to consolidate this logic into a single copy:

```
for node in dir_of_files {
  let model = <What goes here?>::new_from_file(...)?;
  let new_file = <What goes here?>::from(model);
  new_file.export(...)?;
  Ok((node.name.clone())
}
```

Comment: It is possible, if you create a trait for the operations then store a `Box<dyn Trait>`. But I'm not sure this is worth it for those few lines of code.

Comment: Don't be too afraid of repeating yourself. If it's a small amount of relatively stable code, the repetition is often the best solution. It's simple and easy to read. Repetition can become a problem if there's a lot of it, or if the code frequently changes, and you have to manually keep multiple copies in sync.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing you must do is map the runtime file extensions to compile-time types. But once you do that, you can call generic code with the correct types. In this case, you can probably add a default trait method to contain this logic.

```rs
fn manipulate_with_path(path: &Path, node: Node) -> Result<Name, Error> {
    match get_extension(path) {
        "csv" => CsvFile::manipulate(node),
        "sql" => DerivedTable::manipulate(node),
        _ => panic!("Illegal file type passed"),
    }
}

trait Export: From<Model> {
    fn export(self, path: &Path) -> Result<(), Error>;
}

trait Filetype {
    type New: Export;
    fn new_from_file(p: PathBuf) -> Result<Model, Error>;
    fn manipulate(node: Node) -> Result<Name, Error> {
        let model = Self::new_from_file(node.path.to_path_buf())?;
        let new_type = Self::New::from(model);
        new_type.export(&out_path)?;
        Ok(node.name.clone())
    }
}

impl Export for NewCsv {
    fn export(self, path: &Path) -> Result<(), Error> {
        todo!()
    }
}

impl Filetype for CsvFile {
    type New = NewCsv;
    fn new_from_file(p: PathBuf) -> Result<Model, Error> {
        todo!()
    }
}

impl Export for NewTable {
    fn export(self, path: &Path) -> Result<(), Error> {
        todo!()
    }
}

impl Filetype for DerivedTable {
    type New = NewTable;
    fn new_from_file(p: PathBuf) -> Result<Model, Error> {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

There's many things left undefined in your question so I've filled in the gaps with probable types. If you aren't able to adapt this to your situation, add the missing details to your question. In particular, if `Model` is different between each file type, you'll need another associated type in `Filetype`.